# unable to ping an IP from heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am trying to ping to an IP ... I made this application and it works nicely on localhost

```
getAsync('ping google.com').then(data => {
       res.send(data);   
    });
```

at localhost i get

> Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),

but when this code is hosted to heroku ...
the errors in logs are as follows

```
{ Error: Command failed: ping google.com
  /bin/sh: 1: ping: not found
  at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
```

I am making this application as I want to remotely run a .exe which is on machine on that IP

Comment: Heroku is probably not supporting the ping command in their shell

Comment: but ping is bother in windows and linux :(  I had also tried using npm ping package.... the error is still same

Comment: ok..... if you could answer How could I run a .exe file from heroku which is installed on an IP

Comment: I don't think you will be able to run an actual .exe. Isn't Heroku using Linux? Either way, I would suggest you check out Digital Ocean, since Heroku has a lot of limitations and isn't really designed for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

192.168.x.x are [Private network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) IP addresses.
You won't be able to ping them from outside your private network (LAN or whatever you are on).

Comment: ping is not in the default buildpack for heroku. So you either need to find and install a buildpack with it, or create such a buildpack, or in your node.js app implement ping without depneding on the system ping, e.g. with https://www.npmjs.com/package/net-ping