# Child proccess wont launch on heroku hosting

Tags: node.js, heroku, server, discord.js, child-process

So basically, i am creating a discord bot for one server, and i want to add a ping command that would ping a server.
I wrote a working code but when i deploy it to my hosting (heroku) than it just doesnt work properly...

Also, the output from this while deployd on heroku looks like this:

*pinging (some ip)*

And while hosted on my pc it looks like this:

*pinging (some ip)*

*Ping statistics for (some ip):*

*Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),*
*Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:*
*Minimum = 39ms, Maximum = 53ms, Average = 46ms*

also, this is my current code:

```
if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

   if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "ping")) {

    message.channel.send("*pinging (some ip)")

    exec("ping (some ip)", (error, stdout, stderr) => {

      var str = `${stdout}`
      var ping = str.slice(321);

      message.channel.send("Ping statistics for (some ip) :" + "\n" + ping)
    })
```

Comment: Do you have anny error from heroku ? do you try console.log error from exec ? i'm not shure byt when I was using exec command I had to build my own buildpack.

Comment: @Robert yes, i got the error `Error: Command failed: ping localhost
/bin/sh: 1: ping: not found` from heroku.

Comment: [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50020108/unable-to-ping-an-ip-from-heroku) according to comments that i supposed ping is not built in standard buildpack probably you can create your own with ping but i think it can be easier to use this [net ping node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/net-ping)

Comment: i found some [tutorail](https://sendgrid.com/blog/create-first-heroku-buildpack/) but for shure if you can do it with net ping node it will be mutch mutch easier. but building your own buildpack is helpful knowledge